# Scala RedBlackTree syntax

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I was looking at the source of the `RedBlackTree` file and I stumbled upon the definition for `Tree`, the relevant part of which I have copied here:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[A, +B](
@(inline @getter) final val key: A,
@(inline @getter) final val value: B,
@(inline @getter) final val left: Tree[A, B],
@(inline @getter) final val right: Tree[A, B])
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How does `@(inline @getter)` compare to `@inline @getter`?
2. Why are the `val`s qualified with `final`? (Isn't `final` redundant in this context?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@(inline @getter)` syntax is an example of a meta annotation, which tells the compiler that the `@inline` annotation should be placed on the generated getter method (as opposed to the constructer parameter, which would be the default here): [meta annotations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package)

The `final` marks the generated field and getter as final, so they cannot be overridden by subclasses.

This particular combination was used here to trick the Scala compiler into directly accessing the fields of `Tree` instances, instead of calling getters and relying on the JVM optimizer to perform proper inlining. Unfortunately Scala does not provide an officially supported way to use fields directly.

When the redblack tree was optimized for Scala 2.10 this gave the best performance. See the immutable TreeMap/TreeSet [pull request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/82) for the gory details.

Comment: I had already read some of the pull request, but I never noticed the above before, thanks for popping in to explain it!